# How would you call a static method?

Tags: java, jgrasp

I am learning Java. For this assignment, I'm trying to write a program that prompts a cashier to enter each price and quantity, and then a Y for a pet or N for another item. Use a price of -1 as a sentinel. The discount is equal to 20% of the cost of the other items, but not the pets. It has to be one or more pets and at least five other items to receive the discount. I am stuck to call a static method for my main class. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

```
public class DT_PetDiscounter
{
public static double discount(double[] prices, boolean[] isPet, int nItems)
{
   double total = 0;
   double discount = 0;

 for (int i = 0; i < nItems; i++)
  {
  if (isPet[i] == false)
  {
     total = total + prices[i];
  }
 }
      return discount = 0.2 * total;
 }
 }

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Main class to be used for input and output
 */

public class DT_DiscountTester
{
   public static void main(String args[])
  {
  double[] prices = new double[100];
  boolean[] isPet = new boolean[100];
  int i = 0, nPets = 0, nItems = 0;
  String pets;
  int sentinel = 0;

  Scanner scannerObject = new Scanner(System.in);

  while (sentinel != -1)
    {
     System.out.println("Enter the price, or -1 to quit: ");
     sentinel = scannerObject.nextInt();
     if (sentinel == -1)
     break;

     prices[i] = sentinel;
     System.out.println("Is it a pet? y/n");
     pets = scannerObject.next();
     if(pets.equals("y"))
     {
        isPet[i] = true;
        nPets++;
     }
     else
     {
        isPet[i] = false;
        nItems++;
     }
     i++;
     }
     if(nItems >= 5 && nPets >= 1)
     discount(prices,isPet,nPets+nItems);
     System.out.println("The total after the discount is " + discount);       
 }    
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
DT_PetDiscounter.discount(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if (nItems >= 5 && nPets >= 1) 
     discount(prices,isPet,nPets+nItems);
```

to

```
if (nItems >= 5 && nPets >= 1) 
    DT_PetDiscounter.discount(prices,isPet,nPets+nItems);
```

... and *please, please, please* read up on Java Style, and the importance of:

- consistent indentation,
- consistent use of white-space,
- proper choice of identifiers ... including when / how to use underscores in identifiers.  (For example, never in class names!)

---

I hope your lecturer / teacher has explained these things to you.  If not, here's a good place to start:

- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf

Comment: Please note that static methods can ALSO be called on object references

Comment: @javadg - Please also note that you can juggle with scimitars.  Neither of these is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

please use the below code snippet and am sure your issue would get reolved.

```
    double discVal = 0;
    if(nItems >= 5 && nPets >= 1)
        discVal=DT_PetDiscounter.discount(prices,isPet,nPets+nItems);
    System.out.println("The total after the discount is " + discVal);
```